# Ljung-box test of ARIMA-GARCH model for time-series analysis

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals, garch

I am using Python to model my time-series using ARIMA-GARCH model. I follow the given steps (with the assumption that fitting ARIMA first will give me sub-optimal solution):

1. The time series trained on the ARIMA gives me the order of the model: `(4, 0, 4)` based on the best `AIC` value.
2. Next, I compute the model's raw residuals. I plot the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation plots for *square* of these residuals. The plot of ACF suggests me significant autocorrelation among the squared residuals.
3. This implies that there is a presence of volatility clustering in the original time-series. So, using the raw residuals (not the squares) - I fit a GARCH(4, 4) model.
4. The coefficients from ARIMA model will constitute my mean model whereas the coefficients from GARCH model would be used for volatility process.
5. To compute the complete model's diagnostics, I find the **standardized residuals** from the fitted GARCH model (this model was fitted on raw residuals of ARIMA model). Like the volatility process from this GARCH model is the conditional variance model of original time-series, the standardized residuals would be the stochastic piece left out after removing any autocorrelations (please correct me if this understanding is incorrect!). From the standardized residuals (and their squares) I compute the ACF/PACF plots, the Jarque-Bera test values and Ljung-Box test values (Ljung-Box test with `lags=20` and `degrees-of-freedom=20-(p+q)=20-(4+4)=12`). I get following outputs for the same:

```
JBTest (standardized residual): (28398.917863934646, 0.0, -1.373506186939499, 26.104444242955566)
LBTest (standardized residual): (array([31.56722603]), array([0.00161317]))

JBTest (standardized residual square): (40951196.5227887, 0.0, 27.674782313907745, 884.8042719476252)
LBTest (standardized residual square): (array([1.24374803]), array([0.99995272]))
```

So, I can observe that the Ljung-Box test denotes that the square of standardized residuals is `i.i.d`. But, there is some autocorrelation still present in the standardized residuals - given that significance level is `95%`.

Now, I am not sure if my end-to-end understanding is true - But, I feel that the combined model can still be improved (possibly by joined estimations of the individual models), because there is still some correlation left in the standardized residuals of the GARCH model, implying some components which could still be predicted. Please let me know if my thoughts are correct! And, what sort of improvisations can I consider in this situation?